# Mock a DAO class and a method within it

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, dao

I am trying to mock a DAO class that has a method which returns a list of a specific class.

```
private List<SpecificClass> getInfo(){

List<SpecificClass> returnInformation = dao.list(ParamOne, Param Two, SpecificClass.class);
}
```

The dao mentioned in the above method refers to another class.

I begin by mocking that DAO class.

`Mockito.mock(TheDaoClass.class);`

and creating a mocked list

`private @Mock List<SpecificClass> returnedList = new ArrayList<SpecificClass>();`

Then I make call to that method

`dao.list(ParamOne, Param Two, SpecificClass.class);`

and specify what needs to be done when it is called

`when(dao.list(ParameterOne, anyString(), SpecificClass.class)).thenReturn(returnedList);`

When I do the above I get a null pointer exception. There can be two causes:

I understand the list is empty but all it is supposed is hold SpecificClass's five values but that shouldn't throw an error at this point.

I think object `dao` is not getting mocked properly. I am only mocking the whole class `Mockito.mock(TheDaoClass.class)` in order to mock any object asociated with that class. I think that it is not achieving the objective. how do I go about solving this problem? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your mocked DAO object a property of your test class like so:

```
@Mock
private TheDaoClass mockDaoClass;
```

Then, in your `setUp()` method at the beginning of your test class call [`initMocks`](http://mockito.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html#initMocks(java.lang.Object)):

```
@BeforeClass
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

This should prevent the `NullPointer`.

Additionally, I recommend that rather than mock the `List` object (if you are mocking any Java library data type you are probably doing it wrong), you should create a list and populate it.

```
List<SpecificClass> list = new ArrayList<SpecificClass>();
list.add(new SpecificClass());
```

Then return the list from the mocked method.

```
when(mockDaoClass.list(anyString(), anyString(), SpecificClass.class)).thenReturn(list);
```